# How to work xtify simple push api in chrome postman application

Tags: json, postman, xtify

I have tried to rin the xtify simple push api in post manbut it shows error. I have used the following json code in raw body:

```
{

    "apiKey":"12345678-7d94-415a-9eed-00987654321",
    "appKey":"12345678-4ab7-4633-8a7c-00987654321",
    "sendAll": true,
    "content": {
           "message": "Arma virumque cano, troiaeque primus ab oris",
          "sound": "default.caf",
          "badge": "+1",
          "action": {
                    "type": "CUSTOM",
                    "label":"Open",
                    "data": "{'action_id': 'ABC', inum: '123456'}"
          }
     }
}
```

I have valid api key and app key. I have changed here the api key and app key for security reason. Using header Content-Type=application/json but it shows the error message:

> Invalid Application Key

Comment: Try sending a push notification through "Push Point" in the console to make sure that you set up you appKey correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have used this url https://api.xtify.com/2.0/push for sending push. But it should be like this https://euapi.xtify.com/2.0/push. It works now